# @html.Dropdown and twitter bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I want to build a Bootstrap styled dropdown and @HTML.Helper. I know there is a Bootstrap.MVC package, but we don´t wanna go into non standard packages.

We first tried the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.idSelectedEnterprise, Model.Enterprises, new { @class = "dropdown" })
```

But this didn´t gave us a real bootstrap style. On the other hand, if we use a normal bootstrap code like from the bootstrap documentation:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

We don´t know how to plug in the @Model helper that will return the current selected item from dropdown.

This may sound basic, but we need help.

Comment: a dirty work around for this would be to put the selected value into a hidden field and set the field with a jquery click event on the ul

Comment: @MattBodily Without any other input elements, that's going to be the only feasible way to approach this without serializing the entire model into GET parameters on each link (which is going to need even more hacky JS to get the values of other inputs).

Comment: In other words, there is no way to do it... At least for now... Thanks for the input.

Comment: So, do you want use a Bootstrap dropdown in place of a `<select>`, or are you trying to style the `<select>` to look like the Bootstrap dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the insistence on "non-standard packages" - Bootstrap is built (and intended) to be extended as the community requires.

What you are looking for has a few different options; I prefer Bootstrap Select: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/.

It also has a NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap-select

**It's simple to setup:**

Create your `<select>` with the `.selectpicker` class.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Foo, Model.Foos, htmlAttributes: new { @class="selectpicker" })
```

Then call:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```